# ServiceRoute: PUT webservice not working

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, file-permissions

I want to create me WCF services from code with a WebServiceHostFactory like this:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("API", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(MyService)));
```

so I won't need any .svc file. This works until I try to call a `PUT` webservice.
Then will return a method not allowed error. I had solved the problem by setting the write permission on the .svc file to anybody. But now I don't have a .svc file and don't know where to change the permission.

Is there a way to allow `PUT` webservice in a ServiceHostFactory?